# Query MongoDb for Parameter and Return Record with Unique ID

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have to objects with the following properties (only pertinent shown):

Topic: _id, messageIds[],

Reply: _id, creatorId (String), topicId,

What I am trying to do is query for replies created by a specific user (creatorId), but limit the records to only return the most recent message from that user per a particular topic. Since the user may have replied multiple times within a topic, I only want the most recent for each topic they replied in.

I know how to go about performing this action from a brute force perspective (which involves performing two or more separate queries), but I am unsure if the ability exists to do this within the query parameters. If anyone could offer some insight or experience on this I would be grateful. Let me know if you have any additional questions, or if I have left out detail.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing the point, but assuming your `_id` is monotic (which is true for mongos' `ObjectId`s), what about

```
db.replies.find({"topicId" : yourTopicId, "creatorId" : yourCreatorId}).
           sort({"_id" : -1}).limit(1);
```

This will find the most recent reply on a specific topic by a specific author. If the `_id` type isn't monotic, you're out of luck and you'll probably have to investigate the list of `messageIds` in the topic.

Comment: Unfortunately it appears I am out of luck. I'm going to try to find a hash table module to ease the brute force effort.